# How to use set new value to an array object for Emberjs view?

Tags: ember.js

How to use set new value to an array object for Emberjs view?
So I have a table of my data; then when I click edit button I want to change the class of the parent `<tr>` of that button.

So I have this inside my view.

```
{{#each model as |lineItem index|}}
    <tr class="{{ tableRowIndex[index] }}">
        <td>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"
                      {{ action 'editLineItem' this index }} >
                      Edit
                    </a>
                  </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

This is my controller

```
tableRowIndex: computed(function(){

    let array = [];

    this.get('model').forEach(function(){
      array.push("");
    });

    return array;
}),
actions: {
    editLineItem(button,index) {
        console.log(this.get('tableRowIndex'));
        this.set('tableRowIndex[index]','editing-row');
        console.log(this.get('tableRowIndex'));
    },
}
```

But it didn't work out so

```
console.log(this.get('tableRowIndex'));
```

Output the same result before and after I ran

```
this.set('tableRowIndex[index]','editing-row');
```

So how can I make this things work out?

Comment: Instead of `this.set('tableRowIndex[index]','editing-row');` try `this.get('tableRowIndex').objectAt(index,'editing-row')`

Comment: @kumkanillam got this `component.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).objectAt is not a function(…)`

Comment: dont you have `tableRowIndex` array variable with default value for class name?.. if not introduce that property inside model and set that property  value in `editLineItem` method

Comment: @kumkanillam i already declare `tableRowIndex` inside my controller as Array , So i already update my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to set computed property then consider defining it with get and set function.( [refer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties) ).
In your case,you just introduce tableRowIndex and initialize it based on model property in setupController hook of route

```
setupController(controller,model){
   this._super(...arguments);
    let array = [];    
        this.get('model').forEach(function(){
          array.push("");
        });
    controller.set('tableRowIndex',array);
 }
```

and in controller.js,

```
actions: {
        editLineItem(button,index) {
            console.log(this.get('tableRowIndex'));
            this.get('tableRowIndex').objectAt(index,'editing-row')
            console.log(this.get('tableRowIndex'));
        },
    }
```